# remote access to NAS services on subdomains

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, port-forwarding, nas

I've got a NAS that serves multiple services through multiple ports. System administration goes through 8080, bittorrent goes through port 9000, etc. When I'm a t home, I'd type the server's IP and the port to access it, like 10.x.x.x:8080. When I'm away, provided that I forward those ports to the server's IP in the router, I can access the stuff through 123.x.x.x:8080, or 123.x.x.x:9000. If I set up a domain name, I can go mydomain.com:8080, mydomain.com:9000.
That's really useful.

Now suppose that where I am (work, of course), everything is blocked but http. This means that if I wan to access the system administration portion of the NAS, I have to forward http communication from 80 to 8080 into the NAS's IP. That limits my access to one service only. I would like to access them all, but I don't have multiple IP addresses (actually, I barely have one, I use dyndns to track my dinamic IP).

I'm guessing you know where I'm trying to get. I would like to be able to set subdomains like admin.mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com, torrent.mydomain.com and have them all coming through the http port. I believe what I'm looking for is a proxy, or a reverse proxy, I don't know yet, cause I'm not very savvy in this sort of thing. Dyndns does no allow me to set subdomains and even if it did, I could not specify ports for it, only IP addresses. The solution must then be internal, but I don't see my NAS offering any sort of "internal DNS" or internal proxy server.

It does have a virtual host option with the webserver, and I've seen in this post https://serverfault.com/questions/140125/port-to-subdomain a solution that seems to be what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have the wrong site for this question. It'll get migrated automatically to Superuser.

Comment: Do you know what http server the NAS is running?  The apache mod_proxy module would do this but apache is pretty heavy for a NAS.  You could also install squid or some other proxy, but that is dependent on what packages you can install.

Comment: @Paul Well, it's a QNAP Turbo Nas. I did a quick search and couldn't find the exact web server type, but since it runs on an Intel Atom 1.8GHZ processor, it must be able to handle apache. The thing is that I don't think I have easy access to these config files, except for the php.ini file, which I think is a bit useless for this.